# Paramiko: Can't send command on its standard input

Tags: python, ssh, remote-access, paramiko, aix

I am trying to execute the following code to execute a linux command

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Type

import paramiko

class CmdError(Exception):
    ...


@dataclass
class CmdOutput:
    ext_code: int
    out: str


class SSH:
    def __init__(self, hostname, username, password) -> None:

        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.hostname = hostname
        self.ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
        self.ssh.load_system_host_keys()
        self.ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
        try:
            self.ssh.connect(hostname=hostname, username=username, password=password)
        except Exception as e:
            raise e

    def exec_cmd(
        self,
        cmd: str = "",
        CustomException: Type[Exception] = CmdError,
        raise_exception: bool = True,
    ) -> CmdOutput:
        _, stdout, stderr = self.ssh.exec_command(cmd, get_pty=True)
        ext_code = stderr.channel.recv_exit_status()
        out = stdout.read().decode("utf-8")
        err = ""
        if ext_code != 0:
            err = stderr.read().decode("utf-8")
            if raise_exception:
            # Sometimes err is empty, so we need to use out instead
                if err != "":
                    raise CustomException(err)
            raise CustomException(out)
        return CmdOutput(ext_code=ext_code, out=out)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    hostname = "hostname"
    username = "username"
    password = "password"
    ssh = SSH(hostname, username, password)
    cmd = """sudo su - user -Hic direct <<< 'command' """

    print(ssh.exec_cmd(cmd))
```

The command `sudo su - user -Hic direct <<< 'command'` when executed directly in the machine works perfectly, but when executed using paramiko I receive the error

```
sh: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 1 : `<' is not expected.
```

What can I do to execute this command in Paramiko as well? Thank you for the attention.

Comment: `<<<` is a `bash` extension. SSH is using `sh`, not bash.

Comment: Is there any equivalent extension for sh?

Comment: `echo 'command' | sudo su - user -Hic direct`

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! This worked for me. I just need now execute this command with a tag in the final `echo 'command' | sudo su - user -Hic direct -s`. The -s in the final it's not been recognized.

Comment: You need to put `direct -s` in quotes. `-c` only uses the next argument as the command, not all the following arguments.

Comment: I tried `echo 'command' | sudo su - user -Hic "direct -s"` and didn`t worked.

Comment: Are you sure you need `su`? Try `su -u user direct -s`

Comment: This way?  `echo 'command' | su -u user direct -s`

Comment: yeah, that's what I mean.

Comment: It didn`t worked. Paramiko entered in a infinite loop :/